# Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' has no member 'subscript'

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I get an error like this : Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' has no member 'subscript'

I tried to search online but I don't understand, it always says something about changing it to an array of dictionaries but when I parse the data as [[String:AnyObject]] it gives me an error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsiR.png)

Here is my code for context

```
`//
//  MapViewViewController.swift
//  On the Map!
//
//  Created by Belal Elsiesy on 11/13/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Elsiesy Industries. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

import MapKit

class MapViewViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        getLocations()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let locations  = appDelegate.locationData
        var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

        // When the array is complete, we add the annotations to the map.

        for location  in locations! {

            // Notice that the float values are being used to create CLLocationDegree values.
            // This is a version of the Double type.
            let lat = CLLocationDegrees(location["latitude"] as! Double)
            let long = CLLocationDegrees(location["longitude"] as! Double)

            // The lat and long are used to create a CLLocationCoordinates2D instance.
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

            let first = location["firstName"] as! String
            let last = location["lastName"] as! String
            let mediaURL = location["mediaURL"] as! String

            // Here we create the annotation and set its coordiate, title, and subtitle properties
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = "\(first) \(last)"
            annotation.subtitle = mediaURL

            // Finally we place the annotation in an array of annotations.
            annotations.append(annotation)
        }
        // When the array is complete, we add the annotations to the map.
        self.MapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }
}




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
func getLocations() {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://parse.udacity.com/parse/classes/StudentLocation")!)
        request.addValue("QrX47CA9cyuGewLdsL7o5Eb8iug6Em8ye0dnAbIr", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
        request.addValue("QuWThTdiRmTux3YaDseUSEpUKo7aBYM737yKd4gY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil { // Handle error...
                ////////////////////////DO THIS LATER
            }
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
        let parsedResult: [String:AnyObject]!
            do {
                parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as!  [String : AnyObject]


                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.locationData = parsedResult
            } catch {
                print("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")

            }


        }
        task.resume()
    }


`
```

Comment: Because your location variable has no subscript it says you can't use [] to query an info. I think there is a misunderstood about the type of your variable location. It's a tuple (String, Anyobject) and not a dictionnary [String : AnyObject].

Answer (score 6):

From Apple Documentation: You can iterate over the key-value pairs in a dictionary with a for-in loop. Each item in the dictionary is returned as a (key, value) tuple, and you can decompose the tuple’s members into temporary constants or variables as part of the iteration:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print(key)
    print(value)
}
```

And pay attention to another issue with your code:
1) There is async code in function getLocation() and when you assign in viewDidLoad()

```
let locations  = appDelegate.locationData
```

locations equal nil.

2) Swift 4 have useful features for parse JSON, research this. Now you get dictionary with only one key-value pair with key equal "result"

Comment: So how do I fix this.

Comment: There is no fast solution to just fix it. For work with async you can use getLocation(with handler: @escaping: () -> ()) or find another way. For JSON I suggest use separate struct Location to keep data and map JSON to array of this structs. First of all read about work with asynchronous function and about parsing JSON in Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error while trying to sort an array of Tuples. The reason is that Tuple members aren't referenced like Arrays.

**For a Tuple you use `location.latitude`**

*(For an Array you would use `location["latitude"]`)*

Tuples are declared with regular braces, not the square braces for arrays:

```
let location = (latitude: 2.3, longitude: 1.2)

let c = location.latitude   // c is now 2.3
```

I know the question is old, but I hope this helps anyone else searching for *has no member 'subscript'*